# How to get an Array of all days between two days and show it in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

have two dates and want to collect all days between and show it then as a list in DD/MM/YYYY or dd.MM.yyyy format. until now I'can get all days, but have no idea how to cahange the format, maybe somebody have some idea?

here is what i've tryed already:

```
`    https://jsfiddle.net/eqc14y5b/5/    `


   $(document).ready(function () {


var startDate = new Date("2020-01-01").toLocaleDateString(); //YYYY-MM-DD
var endDate = new Date("2020-01-10").toLocaleDateString(); //YYYY-MM-DD

var getDateArray = function (start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = new Date(start).toDateString();
    while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt).toDateString());
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);

// Output
$('#startData').html("<p>Start Date: " + startDate + "</p>");
$('#endData').html("<p>End Date: " + endDate + "</p>");

var res = $('<p></p>');

for (var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {

    res.append('<p>'+dateArr[i]+'</p>');

}

$('#arrayData').html(res);
```

});

and my html:

```
<div id="startData"></div>
 <div id="endData"></div>
 <div id="arrayData"></div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here so we can help you

Comment: take a look, is edited

Comment: title has a typo `ans` --> `and`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this :

```js
var start = new Date("2020-01-01")
var end =  new Date("2020-01-10")
var newend = end.setDate(end.getDate()+1);
var end = new Date(newend);
while(start < end){
   console.log(convertDate(start)); // ISO Date format          
   var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
   start = new Date(newDate);
}


function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat)
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/')
}
```

Comment: and how to put it in my <div> tag?

Comment: store your data like this html +=convertDate(start)+"<br>"; and show in your div like this $("#arrayData").html(html);

Comment: can You show it in a fiddle?  jsfiddle.net/eqc14y5b/5/